# Batch apex : Frist error Apex CPU time limit exceeded

Tags: apex, batch, governorlimits, cpulimit

I am getting CPU time exceeded error for my batch class.

I have 187,000 records to query on and I want to delete all the records.

I am using below query in start method.

```
global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'select Section__c from Object__c';

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<Object__c> AllRecords) {  
     
       
        delete AllRecords;
    
}
```

Comment: The start method is not where you are getting this error.

Comment: You need to [edit] your question to show us what the `execute()` method is doing, provide the full text of the error message and the stack tract (do not paraphrase it), and give us an idea of what other triggers/code are being run.

Comment: I just want to delete all 1,87,000 records from object__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can happen if you have a significant amount of code that runs by way of DML triggers. You may need to reduce the scope size in order to process records. The second parameter to Database.executeBatch controls the scope size.

```
Database.executeBatch(new MyBatchClass(), 100);
```

The default is 200, which may be too big. Try reducing the scope size until you find one that works for your org's situation.

Comment: Id batchJobId1 = Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch, 10);    While executing, I am getting unexpected token batchJobId1  error

Comment: @SFDCDeveloper You forgot to call MyBatch as a method: `Database.executeBatch(new MyBatch(), 10)`